# Tracing, how to filter logs under specified levels for `Layer`?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-tracing

Consider the following code, I am writing the log into both standard output and a file. This is approached by `Layer`, while I don't know how to filter based on level.

```rust
pub fn trace() -> tracing_appender::non_blocking::WorkerGuard {
    let mut log_dir = std::env::current_exe().expect("failed to read cur exe");
    log_dir.pop();
    log_dir.push("server_log");
    let file_appender = tracing_appender::rolling::daily(log_dir, "chat");
    let (non_blocking, guard) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(file_appender);

    let time_offset = offset!(+9);
    let time_description = format_description!("[year]/[month]/[day]-[hour]:[minute]:[second]");
    let timer = OffsetTime::new(time_offset, time_description);

    let file_layer = fmt::layer()
        .with_timer(timer.clone())
        .with_line_number(true)
        .with_thread_ids(true)
        .with_span_events(FmtSpan::ACTIVE)
        .with_file(true)
        .with_writer(non_blocking)
        .with_ansi(false)
        .compact();

    let std_layer = fmt::layer()
        .with_timer(timer)
        .with_line_number(true)
        .with_thread_ids(true)
        .with_file(true)
        .with_span_events(FmtSpan::ACTIVE)
        .compact();

    tracing_subscriber::registry()
        .with(file_layer)
        .with(std_layer)
        .init();

    guard
}
```

How can I avoid Level `Trace` appear in my log? that is, I want only `Info`, `Error`, etc. What if I want different filter level for each layer

Comment: Do you want to set a global filter, or a per-layer filter (for example, only filter the file)?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Global filter is good enough for me, per-layer is even better. But I don't know how to configure them. I saw the example for tracing_subscriber::fmt(), but I am using layer and registry()